extracting clustered genes from heatmap
It might be a stupid question. But is there any way to extract set of genes clustered together in each group? I have expression data file but I want to do gene ontology separately for each disease group.
enter image description here heatmap of differentially expressed genes in 2 disease group

Welcome to SO @Biotechnologist. The short answer is probably, but without any clue on what the data looks like, i.e. a brief 20-row example or at least a hint where the data is from, it's impossible to go deeper on details. For starters, what function was used to get the heatmap? See here for further info.

From the image it looks like you are using the ComplexHeatmap package.
You can split the heatmap's rows into the number of clusters you need and get the row order for each cluster with row_order function. For split heatmap you get row order for each cluster.
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ComplexHeatmap))

# test data (from https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/a-single-heatmap.html)
set.seed(123)
nr1 = 4; nr2 = 8; nr3 = 6; nr = nr1 + nr2 + nr3
nc1 = 6; nc2 = 8; nc3 = 10; nc = nc1 + nc2 + nc3
mat = cbind(rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc1, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc2, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc3, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3))
)
mat = mat[sample(nr, nr), sample(nc, nc)] # random shuffle rows and columns
rownames(mat) = paste0("row", seq_len(nr))
colnames(mat) = paste0("column", seq_len(nc))

# generate heatmap splitting the dendrogram into 2
hm = Heatmap(mat, row_split = 2)
hm = draw(hm) # to avoid the warning



# find row order
ro_list = row_order(hm)
ro_list
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 10  7 18  5  2 16  4 17
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1]  3  1 14 15  9  8 11 12  6 13

# rows from the 1st cluster
rownames(mat)[ro_list[[1]]]
#> [1] "row10" "row7"  "row18" "row5"  "row2"  "row16" "row4"  "row17"

Created on 2024-12-23 with reprex v2.0.2
UPDATE
Another way without redrawing the heatmap is to get the dendrogram object, convert it to hclust, then use cutree function to get the branch you need.
hm = Heatmap(mat)
hm = draw(hm) # to avoid the warning


rdend = row_dend(hm)
row_idx = cutree(as.hclust(rdend), k = 2)
table(row_idx)
#> row_idx
#>  1  2 
#> 10  8

# Note that now the order of branches is different

names(row_idx)[row_idx == 1]
#>  [1] "row1"  "row3"  "row6"  "row8"  "row9"  "row11" "row12" "row13" "row14"
#> [10] "row15"

You can get the same result just clustering the original matrix, if you use the default row clustering method in Heatmap.
hc = hclust(dist(mat))
row_idx = cutree(hc, k = 2)

If your clustering is different from default, you can still use this method applying the corresponding clustering.
